# Как создать документ с содержимым в Google Docs используя api?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Задача - создать документ с нужным контентом в гугл доках.

Тестирую запрос [тут](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22body%22%3A%7B%22content%22%3A%5B%7B%22paragraph%22%3A%7B%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22textRun%22%3A%7B%22content%22%3A%22%3Cp%3EYES%3C%2Fp%3E%5Cn%22%2C%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22bullet%22%3A%7B%22nestingLevel%22%3A0%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22title%22%3A%221488%22%2C%22documentStyle%22%3A%7B%22background%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%7B%22rgbColor%22%3A%7B%22green%22%3A0%2C%22red%22%3A0%2C%22blue%22%3A0%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D).

Сам док - создается, но внутри пустой.

Даже при ответе от сервера получаем

```
body ...
"textRun": {
                "content": "\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
```

Почему же содержимое блока пустое?

Comment: Давайте вопросам нормальное название, плиз

Comment: @Kromster хорошо, сори

Comment: Убрал дополнение,т.к. оно нисколько не проясняет вопрос

Comment: @Kromster я дополнил, чтобы люди не тратили время на то-же самое.

Comment: Вот если бы вы указали конкретно, что и как вы делали и что получили, то это бы помогло. А так - "я все перепробовал ничего не работает" совершенно неинформативно.